# -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

I am getting below error message when trying to run maven commands from eclipse

> -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.

**Update :-** Screen shot added

[image]

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: This error from eclipse only when trying to run from command prompt its working fine.

Comment: ok... but that does not answer my question

Comment: You are using an old Eclipse verison which does not contain the up to date Maven Embedder version. Either you need to update Eclipse to a newer version or you need to install in Eclipse to external Maven version. Window->Preferences->Maven->Installations.

Comment: @khmarbaise That i already using from external source and not maven default setting

Comment: Please check added screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse go this location

```
Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Edit
```

and add these lines in Default VM argument section

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```

Please check below screen shot

[image]

Comment: Wrong way simply.

Comment: @khmarbaise Look like you did not check my updated question